# How to echo lines of file using bash script and for loop

Tags: bash

I have a simple file called dbs.txt
I want to echo the lines of that file to the screen using a for loop in bash.

The file looks like this:

```
db1
db2
db3
db4
```

The bash file is called test.sh
it looks like this

```
for i in 'cat dbs.txt'; do
echo $i
done
wait
```

When I run the file by typing:

```
bash test.sh
```

I get the terminal output:

```
cat dbs.txt
```

instead of the hoped for

```
db1
db2
db3
db4
```

The following bash file works great:

```
cat dbs.txt | while read line
do
echo "$line"
done
```

Why doesn't the first script work?

Comment: fwiw, it's a better practice to use `while read` instead of `for i in $(cat dbs.txt)`

Comment: the first one (even when fixed) would not echo line-by-line if any of the lines contain spaces

Comment: Your single quotes should be back ticks:

<pre>for i in `cat dbs.txt`; do
echo $i
done
wait</pre>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the shell builtin `read` instead of `cat`. If you process just a single file and it's not huge, perhaps the following is easier and more portable than most solutions:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < "$1"
```

I remember reading somewhere that `printf` is safer than `echo` in the sense that the options that `echo` accepts may differ across platforms. So building a habit of using `printf` may be worthwhile.

For description of the `read` builtin, check the manual pages of your shell.

Answer (score 11):

You need to execute a sub-shell and capture the output, like this:

```
for i in `cat dbs.txt`; do
echo $i
done
wait
```

Note the backticks ` instead of the single-quotes.

In bash you can also use `$(command)`:

```
for i in $(cat dbs.txt); do
echo $i
done
wait
```

Comment: See my post, backticks are discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

You need *command substitution* shell feature. This require the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) expression `$()`.

Please, **don't use backticks as others said**.

The backquote (**`**) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html ->  2.6.3 Command Substitution
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Despite of what Linus G Thiel said, `$()` works in `sh`, `ash`, `zsh`, `dash`, `bash`...

Answer (score 1):

you need backticks rather than single quotes

` vs '

Comment: See my post, backticks are discouraged.